# Is there a way to create new tab (aka: “untitled”) from the command line in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublime-text-3

Many answers show how to use Sublime Text from the command line. But I find myself wanting to open a new Sublime Text “untitled” tab from the command line.

This tab in sublime is not yet associated with a file on disk. Basically, just like using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> when Sublime Text is already running.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `subl --help`:

```
Sublime Text build 3095

Usage: subl [arguments] [files]         edit the given files
   or: subl [arguments] [directories]   open the given directories
   or: subl [arguments] -               edit stdin

Arguments:
  --project <project>: Load the given project
  --command <command>: Run the given command
  -n or --new-window:  Open a new window
  -a or --add:         Add folders to the current window
  -w or --wait:        Wait for the files to be closed before returning
  -b or --background:  Don't activate the application
  -s or --stay:        Keep the application activated after closing the file
  -h or --help:        Show help (this message) and exit
  -v or --version:     Show version and exit

--wait is implied if reading from stdin. Use --stay to not switch back
to the terminal when a file is closed (only relevant if waiting for a file).

Filenames may be given a :line or :line:column suffix to open at a specific
location.
```

So, just use `subl -n` (or `--new-window`) to open a new window with an empty tab. If you don't want a new window, use

```
subl --command new_file
```

to open an empty tab in an existing window.

Comment: Wow. I thought i had tried to get help out of subl already. Thanks.  Only a little bit off because I was really asking about how to open a new tab in an existing window.

Comment: @Gabe did you see the bottom of my answer? I tell you how to do exactly that.

Comment: That ends up making a new window. In particular, I am desiring a new tab in an existing window/project.

Comment: @Gabe `subl --command new_file` creates a new tab in the most recently activated Sublime window. I've tested this on Windows, OS X, and Linux with the latest builds of Sublime Text 3.